# ::socket returns 0 and ::connect sets errno to EBADF

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm using BSD sockets and I want to use `::connect` to connect to `example.com` on port 80. The man page of `::socket` tells me that it returns either a valid file descriptor, or `-1` on error.

```
auto fd = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

struct ::sockaddr_in addr;
::bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = family_;

struct ::hostent* hostent = ::gethostbyname(host.c_str());
::bcopy(hostent->h_addr, &addr.sin_addr.s_addr, hostent->h_length);
addr.sin_port = port;

auto err = ::connect(fd,
                     reinterpret_cast<struct ::sockaddr*>(&addr),
                     sizeof(addr));
```

`fd == 0`, so `::socket` succeeded (otherwise it would've returned `-1`). However, `err == -1` and `errno` is set to `EBADF`, indicating that `fd` is a bad file descriptor.

What could be going on here? Why does `::connect` tell me that I gave it a bad file descriptor while I clearly did not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should confirm that `socket` is *actually* returning 0? Unless you've closed the standard file descriptors, that would be very unusual. Make sure you check it immediately after the socket call in case it's being corrupted by the other calls.

Comment: `std::cout << ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) << '\n';` prints `0`. If I set a breakpoint after the call to `::socket`, `fd == 0` tells my debugger me. I didn't close the standard file descriptors, afaik.

Comment: Hmm it appears that by accident I did close file descriptor `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the third argument to the ::socket() call explicitly as IPPROTO_TCP.

```
auto fd = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

The '0' value is IPPROTO_IP, which is not what you need.

Another guess:  try setting

```
addr.sin_addr = htons(port);
```

You might be connecting to something that is unavailable (the port is not 80, as you expect, but 0x5000 == 20480).

Third try. You are using BSD/MacOS, Linux or other POSIX-system ? Or the WinSock ? If windows, check for WSAStartup call.

Comment: Try addr.sin_port = htons(port);

Comment: @Radek'daknok'Slupik: You **have to** use `htons`.

Comment: @ViktorLatypov: "Specifying a protocol of 0 causes socket() to use an unspecified default protocol appropriate for the requested socket type" (which for is TCP for stream sockets).